# Displaying more than one list using for loop in java

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Here is my java code.I have created two lists. I am adding values into it.

```
List customer=new ArrayList();
List roomnumber=new ArrayList();
customer.add(1);
customer.add(2);
roomnumber.add(1);
roomnumber.add(3);
```

Now i want to display the values of both the list in one print statement.
this was my code

```
for(int i=0;i<=roomNumber.size();i++)// Can we have multiple conditions in for loop
{
System.out.format("%d%12d\n",roomNumberList.get(i),customerIDList.get(i));
}
```

This code is not executing....

Answer (score 0):

Loop bound is not correct

```
for(int i=0;i<roomNumber.size();i++)// Can we have multiple conditions in for loop
{
 System.out.println(roomnumber.get(i) + ", " +customer.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we have multiple conditions in for loop

Yes you can.
In simple terms, it is a boolean expression, so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < roomNumber.size() && i < customer.size(); i++)
```

Would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can print it in one statement using `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("Room Number: %d Customer: %d\n",roomnumber.get(i),customer.get(i));
```

also you can put more than one condition in for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < roomnumber.size() &&  i < customer.size(); i++){
      //  statement
}
```

Comment: Can you just look into my System.out statement.I want my output in that format.

Comment: just put `System.out.printf("%d  %d\n",roomnumber.get(i),customer.get(i));`